# How to fix a legend with TraditionalForm

Tags: legending

Let this code

```
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{Sin[x],x>0},{Exp[x], x<=0}}];
Plot[f[x],{x,-5,5}, PlotLegends-> {"f(x)=" TraditionalForm[f[x]]}]
```

Then the part of the `TraditionalForm` in the legend appear braced, as it would be an array. How I can quit the braces? Morover: there is a way that the legend appear with more beautiful fonts (as it would be LaTeX)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends-> {Row[{"f(x) = ", TraditionalForm[f[x]]}]}]
```

[image]

**Note:** To see why you get `TraditionalForm[f[x]]` parenthesized check

```
 "f(x)=" TraditionalForm[f[x]] // FullForm
```

> Times["f(x)=", TraditionalForm[Piecewise[List[List[Sin[x], Greater[x, 0]], List[Power[E, x], LessEqual[x, 0]]], 0]]]

that is, `"f(x)="` is multiplied by `TraditionalForm[f[x]]`.

Comment: one more question: when I evaluate just `TraditionalForm[f[x]]` the output is written using more beautiful fonts than when I did the same inside the legend of a plot. There is a way to put the same fonts in the legend?

Comment: @Masacroso,  If you know the font family you can use `Style[TraditionalForm[f[x]], FontFamily -> fontfamily]` to get the same style in the legend. For best labeling you might want to try  [Szabolcs's MaTeX package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/736/125)