# How can I make publication quality figure in mathematica?

Tags: graphics, export, publishing

It includes adjusting the DPI of the image.

Comment: Use the Rasterize option of Export to control the DPI.

Comment: See this answer in particular: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12