# Exporting plots with Cyrillic text elements to pdf

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, character-encoding, unicode

I'm trying to export a plot with some added notes which happen to be in Russian.

Using Mathematica 8.04 and WinXP I evaluate

```
Export["smt.pdf", "Текст на русском", CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsCyrillic"]
```

Which gives nonsense as output. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Mathematica exports to PDF 1.4, which doesn't deal with certain kinds of OpenType fonts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/666/8) (scroll to bottom of the linked answer).

Comment: I see no issues with this example on Mac OS X (with or without the `CharacterEncoding`).

Comment: @Jens, probably this issues is windows-specific. may be buying mac is one solution))

Comment: Works for me on Win7 mma8.0.1 [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LxWps.png)

Comment: @Ajasja, thanks for your interest. I'm trying this on XP at work though. So the problem it seems is the out-dated os?

Comment: Try opening the pdf with [TexWorks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/). I think it may be PDF viewer related.

Comment: I was wrong.  In older versions it didn't work, but in 8.0.4 it does work.  Try this: `ImportString@ExportString["Текст на русском", "PDF"]`.  No need to use `CharacterEncoding`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks. However it seems that ExportString will not do in my case as I wish to export a plot with notes. I might go with Rasterize and then export images.

Comment: @user829438 That was just a simple way to demonstrate that it works.  `Export` and `ExportString` produce the same data---`Export` will write a readable PDF on my machine (WinXP, Mathematica 8.0.4, like yours).  Test `Export["test.pdf",  "Текст на русском"]` again (precisely as I wrote it, don't include `CharacterEncoding`), and if it still doesn't give you a readable output (try opening with Adobe Reader, that's what I used), then I have one more guess: set the system language to US English, reboot (just in case), and try again.  I know it affects *some* things, e.g. parsing dates.

Comment: So that solves it, thanks. @Szabolcs, would you post it as a solution or is this problem to local?

Comment: @Szabolcs Brilliant! It works, but precisely, we must change the "Language for applications which do not support Unicode" to US English. I should say that after changing this option my computer now runs only in "Safe mode" and changing this option to its default walue does not help (ordinary run of Windows produces blue screen). I use *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on Windows XP SP3. Now I will reinstall Windows since I cannot load it in the usual way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the problem can be solved by setting explicit value of the `CharacterEncoding` global FE option (checked with MMa 8.0.4 and 9.0.0):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
Export["test.pdf", "кириллический текст"]
```

An equivalent way (without changing the global FE settings):

```
Export["test.pdf", 
 Style["кириллический текст", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]]
```

Instead of `"UTF8"` one may set `"UTF-8"` or `"ASCII"` with the same effect. The drawback of this approach is that all non-English letters are outlined.

---

**Update**

Starting from version 10 (checked with versions 10.4.1 and 11.1.1) Cyrillic text is exported correctly with default setting without converting glyphs into outlines:

```
Export["test.pdf", "кириллический текст"] // SystemOpen
```

Here is how exported file looks when opened by Adobe Acrobat 11 (I intentionally selected the first word to show that it isn't outlined):

[image: screenshot]

Moreover, text can be copied from Acrobat and correctly pasted into Notepad.

But importing such PDF as `"Plaintext"` still fails:

```
Import["test.pdf", "Plaintext"]
% // ToCharacterCode
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
>  {1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 8, 32, 9, 6, 1, 7, 9}
> ```

P.S. In versions 10 and 11 `CharacterEncoding` is not recognized as a valid FrontEnd option.

Comment: Alexey, I tried to save (just with the SaveAs menu item) a notebook file with some Russian text cells for my Russian co-authors as a pdf but failed. Could you please kindly comment, if there is the difference in the programmatic and menu exporting. Should I probably just fix CharacterEncoding prior to making file in order to later SaveAs a pdf?  I have Mma 11.1.1.0 and Win7.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes, there were many reports on this site that menu exporting produces different results (usually with much lower quality) than `Export`. So `Export` is always the preferred method. Printing to a virtual PDF printer is another option, and it usually allows to workaround problems with non-English letters (and usually it produces graphics with much better quality than menu exporting, but still not as good as `Export`).

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I just tried to `Save As...` a Notebook with some Russian text as PDF and got a correct PDF (*Mathematica* 11.1.1 on Win7 x64). There is a possibility that you use some non-standard fonts with which *Mathematica* has troubles. If so, try exporting with default fonts.