# Exporting Cyrillics in PDF on Linux

Tags: export, pdf-format, fonts, linux, character-encoding

I'm using Mathematica from Ubuntu. I need a normal font to display cyrillics inside PDFs. Any default font is very ugly, letters are too close together:

```
ImportString@
  ExportString[Style["Русский", FontFamily -> #, FontSize -> 50], 
   "PDF"]&/@ {"Times", "Courier", "Arial"}
```

[image]

Here is the longer example with also Latin mixed in:

[image]

As you can see Cyrillics letters are much bigger somehow.

It's happening to every text inside the notebook including graphics, even though it looks fine in the editor.

This is how it looks on `MacOSX-x86-64` and Mathematica 8.0.4 which can be used as reference:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5660/121 (Sadly, no answers.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've seen it. I don't have nonsense in the output I just got ugly fonts.

Comment: I understand now.  Hopefully this one will be answered.

Comment: This may be system dependent. On my OS, Win7-64 using Mathematica 8.0.4. I get [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJnvC.png) which looks good to me.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, I'm on linux

Comment: Using the exact same fonts in a text processor do you get better results? I wonder whether you have Arial, for instance, as this is usually distributed with Windows and MacOS, but I believe not with Linux.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Text processor display everything fine, it's the exported PDF only that got this problem and if I print something of course since it converts to PDF first. And I have Arial, it's last in the picture.

Comment: Did you install Arial yourself or did it come with your distribution?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Not sure, I've installed a lot of things, maybe some package came with Arial (probably wine).

Comment: On macosx7.5 mma 8.0.4 I get the same result as Sjoerd

Comment: For pdf files advance option **ISO 19005-1 Compliant (PDF/A)** embeds the fonts. If generating a PDF, you may use any fonts you like, but you must embed the fonts in the PDF. Keep in mind, that you may not have the printing rights for a font and that some fonts are only screen fonts and can't be used to print. With these kinds of fonts, you will not be able to embed them in your PDF or if they do embed, they won't print correctly. But not sure how to do it in mathematica...

Comment: Maybe you can create an empty cyrillics embedded pdf file and append the Mathematica work there...

Comment: @s.s.o But I would rather just select and export or print directly from Mathematica. Currently I forced to export as PNG and using TeX to make PDFs.

Comment: If you can print as pdf file, then go to pdf printer preferences and change **default settings** to  **ISO 19005-1 Compliant (PDF/A)**. I hope your pdf printer has preferences options.

Comment: @s.s.o There are no any pdf printer options.

Comment: @swish Can you include the text in *copyable text* so I can use to test the stuff?

Comment: @halirutan [Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) can provide as much copyable text as needed.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion you don't have many options here and honestly, I would not try to achieve this with *Mathematica* and Linux because the font-rendering was, is and will at least for some time be crappy. In the examples, I use the "Liberation Serif" which is the default serif font on my system.

Let me give some ideas: The easiest thing I know is to use `FontTracking` to widen the characters.

```
ImportString@
   ExportString[
    Style["Русский", FontFamily -> "Liberation Serif",
      FontSize -> 50, FontTracking -> "Wide"], "PDF"] // 
  First // Framed
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you see the "y" is still touching the "P" and "Wide" is the maximal possible setting to this option. This brought me to my second idea where you adjust the low-level boxes to make the spacing right. Basically it works like that:

You split your string into characters and `Riffle` and invisible space between each character. This invisible space is wrapped in an `AdjustmentBox` where you have the option to set margins to all directions.

An outer `StyleBox` takes all your options for `FontSize` and so on. To see the spacing even to the left, right, bottom and top of the string, I used a `FrameBox`

```
ImportString@
  ExportString[
   FrameBox@
     StyleBox[
      RowBox[Riffle[Characters["Русский"], 
        AdjustmentBox["\[InvisibleSpace]", 
         BoxMargins -> {{0.15, 0}, {1, 1.5}}], {2, -1, 2}]], 
      FontFamily -> "Liberation Serif", FontWeight -> Plain, 
      FontSize -> 50] // DisplayForm, "PDF"] // First
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### How to implement the method 1

Try first the easy way which is to select appropriate fonts and setting the `FontTracking` to "Wide". This is more fiddling than a science but what I basically tried was the following. I created two text-cells with the same content. I leave the first one as it is and adjust the second to try what changes. If you find settings which are *acceptable*, you can transfer them into a stylesheet and use it.

So here is my test-environment. Create a new document from within a notebook, this will make saving the pdf and looking at the result much easier:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];
Button["SAVE ME!",
 Export["/home/oliviaWild/Desktop/cyrillicTest.pdf", nb]]
```

Create 3 text-cells, where the first and the second one contain the same cyrillic text and the last one maybe an upper-case (see `ToUpperCase`) English text for comparison.

First thing is, to set the font manually by marking the second cell and using Format->Font. Then save the document and check in you pdf viewer, whether the font is embedded (in evince, File->Properties->Fonts). I used `DejaVu Serif` and get the following font properties in the pdf viewer

[image]

See, that the default text-cells use `Times` which could not be embedded since it is not installed.

Go again in the second text cell and press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E`. You can append the FontTracking option there

```
е).\\>","Text",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.5602729176824493`*^9},
 FontFamily->"DejaVu Serif",FontTracking->"Wide"]
```

Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E` again and see the pdf. Like this you can play with all settings, either by marking the cell and use the *Format` menu or by adding the appropriat option directly in the cell expression.

When you are finished, you can store this in a style-sheet by using *Format->Edit Stylesheet* and selecting *Text* under "Choose a style". Click on this text cell, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E` and add the font options at the end:

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"],FontFamily->"DejaVu Serif",FontTracking->"Wide"]
```

Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`E` and store the stylesheet.

### How to implement the method 2

This is more work and I don't have time to investigate in this right now but what you basically have to do is to implement a function which transforms your text into this low-level box style. For some words *Mathematica* is doing this automatically. Make to text-cells, in the first you type "Latex is nice", in the other "LaTeX is nice". Look at the underlying expressions and you see that the word "LaTeX" was transformed in the same way I did above.

Comment: It's surely looks great but how to apply it to every cyrillic text in the notebook before printing?

Comment: Can you updated your question by giving a longer text, maybe 3-4 sentences, and by explaining exactly where the text appears? Is it in input-cells, text-cells, ..?

Comment: It still doesn't solve an oversized letters over Latin. I think what requires tweaking are some font system settings and not Mathematica.

Comment: @swish And it would really help to some of the developers, which works on the front-end in Linux. Unfortunately, John Fultz is the only FE expert I know and he is working on Windows only to my knowledge.